# Spring boot tomcat access logs for management port not logged in console

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logging, spring-boot-actuator, access-log

Have added the following in my application.yaml

```
server:
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
      directory: /dev
      prefix: stdout
      buffered: false
      suffix:
      file-date-format:
```

if i make management port same as app port then it works fine. I am expecting logs such as below

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [12/Apr/2021:11:53:00 +0530] "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 200 25
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [12/Apr/2021:11:53:00 +0530] "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 200 25